# Swift annotation location update

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, cllocationcoordinate2d

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class ServisimNeredeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var coordinates: [[Double]]!
    var names:[String]!
    var addresses:[String]!
    var phones:[String]!

    var locationManager :CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let singleton = Global.sharedGlobal

    let point = ServisimAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.052466 , longitude: 29.132123))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        coordinates = [[41.052466,29.108976]]// Latitude,Longitude
        names = ["Servisiniz Burada"]
        addresses = ["Furkan Kutlu"]
        phones = ["5321458375"]
        self.map.delegate = self

        let coordinate = coordinates[0]

        point.image = UIImage(named: "direksiyon")
        point.name = names[0]
        point.address = addresses[0]
        point.phone = phones[0]
        self.map.addAnnotation(point)

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I add the coordinate's annotation when the first screen is loaded I update the newly set coordination when the button is pressed. I want instant update of location when button is pressed. How can I do it?

```
@IBAction func tttesttt(_ sender: Any) {
    self.point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.192846, longitude: 29.263417)       
}
```

Does not update the new location when you do the above operation. But the coordination is eliminated and the new one is updated instead I did it like this, but it did not happen again

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: surucuKordinant.latitude!, longitude: surucuKordinant.longitude!)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The likely issue is that your `configuration` property has not been configured for key-value observing (KVO), which is how the map and/or annotation view become aware of changes of coordinates.

I would ensure that `coordinate` is KVO-capable by including the `dynamic` keyword. For more information, see the [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID12) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns.*

Clearly, we don't have to do all of that observer code in that KVO discussion (as MapKit is doing all of that), but we do at least need to make our annotation KVO-capable. For example, your annotation class might look like:

```
class ServisimAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    ...
}
```

The failure to declare `coordinate` as `dynamic` will prevent key-value notifications from being posted, and thus changes to the annotation will not be reflected on the map.